# comprehensive list of graphics object types matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I could not find a comprehensive graphics object types list that could be especially useful to find an modify objects in matlab plots such as:

```
findall(gcf,'Type','Line'); %get all line objects in the current figure
```

To be more precise: I'm looking for a list of possible input after the argument 'Type'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to get the comprehensive list, but you can get the list of types for existing objects:

```
types = unique(get(findall(gcf, '-property', 'Type'), 'Type'));
```

Practically I think this is enough, since we are not interested in those non-existing objects.

Comment: Really good way to find! You can also get some extra information running: "findall(gcf)"

Comment: it's not specifically what I asked for but exactly as usable if not more useful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access to all graphics objetcs through the packages embedding the type of one plot. For this, use `metaclass` to go through metadata of a plot type:

```
h = plot(rand(10,1));
% h is of type Line
```

Now we use metaclass to get all metadata about class Image:

```
metah = metaclass(h);
```

One nice feature is that it references the `ContainingPackage`, in which we can acces to all classes through `ClassList`. In each class you can get the name, classs metadata, and ways to navigate through class hierarchy.

For our purpose, I simmply get the complete list of primitive graphics with

```
{metah.ContainingPackage.ClassList.Name}
```

It gives the following list (after sorting) on R2017b:

```
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Area'         }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Bar'          }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Binscatter'   }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.ConstantLine' }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Contour'      }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Data3D'       }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.ErrorBar'     }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.FunctionLine' }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot'    }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Heatmap'      }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Histogram'    }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Histogram2'   }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line'         }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Quiver'       }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Scatter'      }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Stair'        }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Stem'         }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface'      }
{'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.brushingUtils'}
```

Last one is not a graphics primitive. You can see that it lacks classes like `Image`, which can be accessed through the same process:

```
h = image(rand(5));
metah = metaclass(h);
sort({metah.ContainingPackage.ClassList.Name}.'}
```

which gives:

```
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Data'          }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Group'         }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Image'         }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Light'         }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'          }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Marker'        }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Patch'         }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Polygon'       }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Rectangle'     }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Surface'       }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.SurfaceXYZData'}
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'          }
{'matlab.graphics.primitive.Transform'     }
```

Some classes seem to be in both packages. I think the second list is the core classes and the first list some dedicated classes for line charts (not patched). But this is just a guess.

I think we should have all basic graphics classes, or that there are other graphics that are in other packages -- if anyone knows what are these other packages, let us know!

**EDIT**
Finally I've found the page of the documentation listing all graphic objects. See [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-object-properties.html)